# Windows keep getting update and fill the drive gradually

Tags: windows

I want to be up to date. But don't want my drive get filled up. Can I delete extra files which saves windows inside?

Comment: Windows will automatically delete the installation files for any windows updates you receive on a periodic basis, in order to save your disk space.

Comment: "Can I delete extra files which saves windows inside?" - What files exactly do you want to delete?

Comment: To be sure you can check the `c:\windows\softwaredistribution\` folder and delete what’s inside.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.   Use Disk Cleanup for this.

Run Administrative Tools, Disk Cleanup.

When it comes up, click on Cleanup System Files.

Allow this to run. Select ALL items so that Disk Cleanup does a complete job.

Disk Cleanup will ask about deleting (cleaning up) Windows.old. If your computer is running fine, say OK to this and Windows.old will be cleaned up.

This can save 20 GB of space depending on your particular computer.

I use this tool frequently

[image: Disk Cleanup]

Disk Cleanup will clean up files from Updates. Other files are yours, and you can set up File History cleanup in Windows Settings. This is more gradual and takes place over time.